# $add only supports numeric or date types, not array Error when Incrementing in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregate

I have a document that looks like this:

```
{ 
  "_id": ObjectId("1111"), 
  "products":[
   {
    _id:'abc',
    quantity:3},
   {
    _id:'xyz',
    quantity:5
   }
 ]
}
```

I need to increment the subdocument products.quantity by a certain amount.

This is what I have tried so far

```
Counter.findOneAndUpdate(
 { "_id": ObjectId("1111"), "products._id": 'abc' },

 [{
  $addFields: {
   'products.quantity': { $add: [ "$products.quantity", 7 ] }
  }
 }])
```

When I run this, I would expect the quantity to be 10,but I get an error which says that **$add only supports numeric or date types, not array**

Now how can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to update quantity for all elements in products array ?

Comment: @whoami No, It is just one element in the array that matches the filter ie "products._id": 'abc' as shown in my question

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array filters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) to filter by desired position and [$inc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) to increment the value like this:

```
Counter.findOneAndUpdate({
  _id: "1111",
  "products._id": "abc"
},
{
  $inc: {
    "products.$[element].quantity": 7
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "element._id": "abc"
    }
  ]
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KggKV64BcjW)

By the way, the problem why are you getting `$add only supports numeric or date types, not array` is because `"$products.quantity"` are all values from the array. In your example the value is `[{quantity:3},{quantity:5}]`. Then you have to filter the exact value you want to get the number, and not the array.